# Null Pointer Exception while upgrading to Tomcat 8.5.51

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat8

Trying to upgrade tomcat to fix [`Ghostcat`](https://www.chaitin.cn/en/ghostcat) breach. I tried to override the tomcat version from 8.5.29 coming through `spring-boot-starter-tomcat 1.5.11.RELEASE` to `Tomcat 8.5.51`.
This gives me NPE at webSocket. Below is my `build.gradle` snippet and the error trace.
Has anyone faced this issue? Any suggestions how to fix this please?

Build.gradle:

```
providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '1.5.11.RELEASE'
     compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-core', version: '8.5.51'
     compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-el', version: '8.5.51'
     compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-websocket', version: '8.5.51'
     compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-annotations-api', version: '8.5.51'
```

ERROR:

```
2020-03-03 14:25:47.050 ERROR 8383 --- [tp1587487668-17] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [null]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:50) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.51.jar:8.5.51]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83) ~[jetty-servlets-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:294) ~[jetty-servlets-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:244) ~[spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-1.5.11.RELEASE.jar:1.5.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.5.11.RELEASE.jar:1.5.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92) [spring-boot-1.5.11.RELEASE.jar:1.5.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-1.5.11.RELEASE.jar:1.5.11.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:447) [jetty-servlet-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:540) [jetty-security-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1070) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:376) [jetty-servlet-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1004) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:258) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:449) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:252) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:266) [jetty-server-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:240) [jetty-io-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) [jetty-util-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520) [jetty-util-9.0.0.v20130308.jar:9.0.0.v20130308]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
```

Comment: There is known issue of Spring Boot with Tomcat https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22131. Maybe updating spring-boot-starter-tomcat is required.